# can't upload uiimage from ios to server with php

Tags: php, ios, image, upload, server

Here is my code:

```
NSString *image_name = @"test.jpg";
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.myImage.image, 0.1);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx/uploadfile.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",image_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

and here the php code:

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = 'C:\'; 
$file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file; 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    { echo "Received file" . $_FILES; } 
?>
```

but it doesn't work. Responsestring says:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the IOS side

```
- (IBAction)uploadImage {
    /*
     turning the image into a NSData object
     getting the image back out of the UIImageView
     setting the quality to 90
    */
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = @"http://XXXXX.com/test-upload.php";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
    */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
    */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
}
```

Here is the php function to grab the uploaded file:

```
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://XXXXXXX.com/uploads/{$file}";
}
```

After That you need to use xampp or WAMMP Go to that directory where your PHP Project put give full access and one more think to need to create one folder inside that project call as `uploads` for this tutorial.